# Python regex string matching with varying search string

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there anyway in python to be able to perform:

```
"DDx" should match "01x", "10x", "11x, "00x"
```

in an elegant way in Python?

The easiest way I see to do this is by using regex, which in this case would be:
`re.search('\d\dx',line)`

Is there anyway to dynamically update this regex?
In case the input is:
 `"D0x"` then regex: `\d0x`

Please help.

Using Python 2.7

**EDIT**

In simpler terms, my question is:

```
>>> str = "DDx"
>>> str.replace('\d','D')
>>> re.search(<use str here>,line)
```

Or any alternate approach

Comment: ...so you're asking how to make a string lowercase, and put a backslash in front of it?

Comment: hmm..kind of, yeah but I can do the str.replace thingy but I need to use the new string in searching

Comment: I am sorry, I should have given it a bit more thought...I found the answer

Comment: Or you can keep a dictionary of key verses matching regex. {'DDx':r'\d\dx'}

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
>>> s = "DDx"
>>> s = s.replace('D','\d')
>>> p = "01x"
>>> c = re.search(s,p)
>>> print c.group(0)
>>> "01x"
```

Comment: You will get an exception if you access group when there is no match. If you get None on re.search you can assume there is no match.

Comment: @user3885927 Yes, I plan on using re.findall as the strings against which I search are list elements...I can handle exceptions through that...good point though